# Running executable with command line parameters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command, execute

This has to be possible.  I am able to open a command prompt in windows and do the following:

```
<some exe> <some exe command line parameters>
```

There must be an equivalent way to do this in PowerShell or even a standard windows batch file.  For example, from the windows command prompt I can start a docker container with:

```
docker run –-net=kafka -d –-name=zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0
```

however if I try something like this with PowerShell

```
& "docker" run –-net=kafka -d –-name=zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0
```

it fails with an generic error:

```
invalid reference format.
```

Perhaps PowerShell is not suited for this type of advanced use case.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Is there a better scripting language for advanced usages like this?

Comment: As an aside: This is definitely not an _advanced_ use case: invoking a console application with arguments is a core feature of any shell, including PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

By and large, external programs in PowerShell are called the same way as from `cmd.exe` - there are differences, due to PowerShell having additional metacharacters such as `$` and `@`, but they do not come into play in your specific case.
(Your `& "docker" ...` variant would work in principle too, but the use of `&` is only necessary if you must use a *quoted* or *variable-based* command name or path).

**The problem is that your original command line contains two instances of `–` ([EN DASH, `U+2013`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013)) instead of the expected ASCII-range `-` dash (hyphen)**, which `docker` doesn't recognize.

A quick way to discover the problem:

```
# Print the code points of characters outside the ASCII range.
PS> [int[]] [char[]] '& "docker" run –-net=kafka -d –-name=zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0' -gt 127
8211
8211
```

Decimal `8211` is hex. `0x2013`, the code point of en-dash, whereas the code point of the regular `-` is `45` (`0x2d`).

All that is needed is to replace these `–` instances with `-` (and, since `docker` needn't be quoted, there is no need for `&`):

```
docker run --net=kafka -d --name=zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0
```

---

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56069725/45375) shows a variable-based implementation of the command that is *effectively the same* as the command above - if all the arguments are known in advance, there is never a *need* to use variables.

If you do want to use variables, it is much simpler to use a *single array variable* for all the arguments and pass that:

```
$dockerExe =  'docker'
$dockerArgs = 'run',
              '--net=kafka',
              '-d',
              '--name=zookeeper',
              '-e',
              'ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181',
              'confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0'

& $dockerExe $dockerArgs
```

Note:

- The executable name/path must always be specified separately, and if it is *quoted* or involves *variable references* (as in this case), `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-) must be used for invocation, for syntactic reasons.
- Passing the arguments as an array this way works with *external* programs; for PowerShell commands, you'd create a *hashtable* variable that you pass with sigil `@` instead of `$`, a feature known as [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

Answer (score 0):

I think Start-Process cmdlet will be useful. ArgumentList can be single or double quoted.

`Start-Process docker -ArgumentList "run –-net=kafka -d –-name=zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0"`

Comment: This doesn't solve the true problem of the command line containing em-dashes instead of hyphens, but even if it did, it would fundamentally change the behavior of the invocation: by default, `Start-Process` creates a new window and runs asynchronously - it is simply the wrong tool for normal, synchronous invocation of console applications such as `docker`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of complexities in powershell escaping. I wrote this module to assist with running of external commands:

https://github.com/choovick/ps-invoke-externalcommand

Demo:
https://terminalizer.com/view/49acb54a979

```
Install-Module -Name ExternalCommand -Scope CurrentUser
Invoke-ExternalCommand -Command "docker" -Arguments @("run","-d","--name=zookeeper","--net=kafka","-e","ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181", "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0")
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to do it.

```
$app = 'docker'

$a1 = 'run'

$a2 = '--net=kafka'

$a3 = '-d'

$a4 = '--name=zookeeper'

$a5 = '-e'

$a6 = 'ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181'

$a7 = 'confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0'

& $app $a1 $a2 $a3 $a4 $a5 $a6 $a7
```

Comment: This does nothing different than `docker run --net=kafka -d --name=zookeeper -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0`. If you do need to provide the arguments via variables, declare an _array_ (`$a = 'run', '--net=kafka', ...`) and pass that (`docker $a`).

Comment: the accepted answer above demonstrates how to run a command with parameters in powershell.

Comment: True, your answer demonstrates _one_ way to run a command with parameters in PowerShell, but it is an unnecessarily complicated and therefore ill-advised way - and it is effectively the same as the normal, direct invocation shown in my first comment, so it can't be the solution to your problem as presented in the question.

Comment: its definitely a solution as the one in the first comment doesn't work and this one does. :-)

Comment: The only reason it is a solution is because you _retyped_ your arguments, and thereby _happened to_ eliminate the true source of the problem: your original command line accidentally uses 2 EN DASH characters instead of regular dashes (hyphens) - please see my answer. Your invocation style is ill-advised and unrelated to the true solution.